# PyQt5 QFileDialog Aborted (core dumped)

Tags: 20.04, python, pyqt5

Following are the outputs of some commands.

===========================================

### lsb_release  -a

No LSB modules are available.

Distributor ID: Ubuntu

Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS

Release:    22.04

Codename:   jammy

===============================================

### python --version

Python 3.11.4

================================================

### pip list | grep "Py"

PyAudio                        0.2.13

Pygments                       2.15.1

PyQt5                          5.15.10   <---

PyQt5-Qt5                      5.15.2    <---

PyQt5-sip                      12.13.0   <---

PySocks                        1.7.1

PyYAML                         6.0

QtPy                           2.3.1

===========================================================

When i instantiate the class `QFileDialog` gives me the following error and the program gets crashed. I tried using a static call to `QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Open Image File', '', 'Images (*.png *.jpg *.jpeg *.bmp *.gif)')` and an instance call `QFileDialog().getOpenFileName(self, 'Open Image File', '', 'Images (*.png *.jpg *.jpeg *.bmp *.gif)')` but both of them gives the same error. I also tried them on another ubuntu system and it is working well there.

python3.1 example.py

QSocketNotifier: Can only be used with threads started with QThread

malloc(): invalid size (unsorted)

Aborted (core dumped)